# Fetching Results from Stored Procedure R

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, rodbc

I'm wondering how one would fetch results from a stored procedure in R. I'm currently using RStudio with the RODBC package and am using

```
sqlQuery(conn, 'exec sp_name vars')
```

as my query. The stored procedure is supposed to return back an integer representing the new row number the data is generated on. How would I go about this? At the moment I get `-2` or `character(0)` back on my executions.

Just trying to return a number and store it R side.

**Stored Procedure**

```sql
USE [Internship]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[pCreateKMeanTest]    Script Date: 7/20/2017 12:51:28 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO





ALTER procedure [dbo].[pCreateKMeanTest] 
    (@DataSetName varchar(255)
    ,@SQLStatement varchar(5000) 
    ,@ColumnUsed varchar(2900)
    ,@TotClusters int )

as

/*
exec pCreateKMeanTest 
     @DataSetName = '[dbo].[vAccountMemberProductDetailWithBehavior]'
    ,@SQLStatement = 'select [demo_age], Profit_PnlAmt, Census_HomeNearestBranchDistance from [dbo].[vAccountMemberProductDetailWithBehavior]'
    ,@ColumnUsed = 3
    ,@TotClusters = 5
*/


begin transaction

insert into dbo.KMean
    (ExecutedDateTime
    ,DataSetName
    ,SQLStatement
    ,ColumnUsed
    ,TotClusters)
select 
     getdate()
    ,@DataSetName
    ,@SQLStatement
    ,@ColumnUsed
    ,@TotClusters

select max(TestID) from dbo.KMean (nolock)

commit transaction



GO
```

Comment: Can we see your stored procedure? Is it a user-defined sp or a built-in one as `sp_name` suggests so? There may be security issues running system procs via odbc.

Comment: @Parfait That is the stored procedure code.

Comment: Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` inside stored proc and move the last `SELECT max(...)` query outside the transaction.

Comment: @Parfait Thank you that was perfect!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented and since it may help future readers:

For SQL Server stored procedures, add a `SET NOCOUNT ON` to avoid the row results output that may interfere with RODBC's `sqlQuery` which expects  table/query data to be returned.

And generally for most stored procedures, move any `SELECT` statement outside a transaction block that is executing an action query (i.e., `UPDATE`, `INSERT INTO`) if needing to return actual data.

Comment: does this `SET NOCOUNT ON` advice hold for the relatively new `odbc` package as well? The DBI maintainers and rstudio devs are working hard to make it the successor of `RODBC`.

Comment: Good question. But seeing this is more a SQL Server issue in returning a non tabular output, I do not know how authors can work around it. Here, nothing on R side needed change.